# vba - looping over specific form controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have an access form with like 5 dropdowns boxes, I need to check if the values of the dropdown boxes are unique before I approve the form. I can iterate over all the form elements but I want to be able to iterate only over  dropdowns:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id1 [dropdown values] Id2 [Dropdown values]  Id3 [Dropdown Values]   |
|                                                                     |  
|  CollectionTask [Another dropdown]                                  |    
|  []This is a checkbox                                               |
|               [Approve Button] [clear myForm btn]                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------

'iterating over the form elements 
 On Error Resume Next
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        'do something only for dropdown controls of form
    Next
```

Instead of iterating over everything, I want to iterate over only the dropdown types. I feel like there should be a way to do it. I am working around this using the technique below but that's a lot of code.

```
'this code will do the trick but that means I will have to write a condition for every id
'which for me is lots of code (not being lazy but I think iterating over the form elements will be more efficient 
If (id1.Value = id2.Value) Or (id1.Value = id3.Value) Or (id1.Value = id4.Value) then
       Msgbox "make sure you are not duplicating ids"

End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code you can check all controls with the `ControlType` of `acComboBox`.  Basically it just adds the `ComboBox`'s value into an `Dictonary` checking each time to see if the value already exists in the `Dictonary`.  You just need to determine what you want to happen if the value is already set in another `ComboBox`.

This is freehand code but I am fairly certain everything is correct:

```
 Private Sub CheckCombos()
     Dim ctl As Control
     Dim dict As Variant

     Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


     For Each ctl In Me.Controls

         If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then 

             If Nz(ctl.Value,"") <> "" Then 

                 If dict.Exists(ctl.Value) Then 
                    Msgbox "Combobox: " & ctl.Name & " has the same value as: " & dict(ctl.Value)
                 Else 
                    dict.Add ctl.Value, ctl.Name
                 End If

             Else 
                 Msgbox "Empty Combobox" 
                 'Handle exit
             End If 

         End If
     Next
  End Sub
```